# Calling an External Perl Script From Within XSLT

Tags: perl, xslt, call

How would I go about calling an external Perl script, or any script, from within an xslt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at the `register_function()` method in `XML::LibXSLT`. The `XML::LibXSLT` documentation has a small example how to register a small perl function to be used in an XSLT stylesheet. From personal experience, there's no problem to define also larger functions here.

Comment: That is a nice feature, but it is worth iterating that this is implementation-specific functionality.

Comment: The XSLT specification mentions and allows [extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#extension) in the xslt language. And of course it's implementation-specific; a python xslt implementation is unlikely to support perl code. If your goal is portability, then don't use this feature. If not, then I don't know of any obstacles for using this feature.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I'm not dealing with any browsers. The XSL that I'm writing is to generate XML to send to a database. Nothing I work with will go beyond the content management system besides the XML. The CMS captures the user's work area information and user data, using perl, we can capture that information and send it along as metadata in the xml. However, unless XSL can grab information like that, using built in perl functions is the way to go. Thanks again @SlavenRezic!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any sense. Tying an XSLT *stylesheet* to external commands would void any portability, especially to browsers.

Specific XSLT processors could allow scripting¹, but this won't be generally available. The [XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) does not contain *anything* related to calling external commands. The spec does say how extensions to the language are handled, which makes it possible for vendors to include supports for scripting or calling external commands.

If your problem cannot be solved in the (Turing-complete) XSLT language, then it may be the wrong tool for your job. Rewriting some parts in Python or Perl may be more appropriate.

<sub>1. A Microsoft implementation allows you to define extra functions in JavaScript.</sub>

Comment: My goal is to add data paths from a datacapture template from within a content management system. Previously we used Perl to generate the templates so writing the functions within were standard. We are Moving to XSL, I'm trying to find a way to leverage that data since it will not be user defined content.

Comment: @AndersonNicholasL You can process multiple input documents, which can be referenced by URIs. If the other content is static, this is trivial (just dump the extra XML to a file, and be done with it). Otherwise, you could somehow bind a script to a specific URL, e.g. through CGI – but that would be a very questionable design.

Comment: @amon Please see my answer. It's perfectly fine to register external functions for xslt.